# SwiftUI - List gives error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to implement a List with Multiple selection.

This is the Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiSelectionWithEditButton : View {
    var items = ["One","Two", "Three"]

    @State var selectedRows = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List((items, id: \.self), selection: $selectedRows) { name in
                Text(name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Selected \(selectedRows.count) rows"))
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct MultiSelectionWithEditButton_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MultiSelectionWithEditButton()
    }
}
#endif
```

But I get error bellow:

"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

[image]

Appreciate if anyone can help! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in yours `List`s init. Change it to `List` with `ForEach` inside, like below:

```
struct MultiSelectionWithEditButton : View {
    var items = ["One","Two", "Three"]

    @State var selectedRows = Set<String>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selectedRows){
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Selected \(selectedRows.count) rows"))
        }
    }
}
```